# Default size in Azure AI (Cognitive) Search

Tags: azure, search, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

I am using Azure cognitive search with Cosmos DB.
I have gone through some documentation of Azure Cognitive search. They mentioned the default size of an Index for querying the data is 1000 only.

Is there any way I can increase the batch size to 2000 or 3000 in a single call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity#indexer-limits),

- The default batch size for search requests in Azure Cognitive Search is **1,000 documents**.
- The maximum allowed batch size is **10,000 documents**.

To fetch more data in the Azure portal or using the REST API, set the `$top` parameter in your search request to the desired batch size (up to the maximum of 10,000).

`https://<your-search-service-name>.search.windows.net/indexes/<your-index-name>/docs?api-version=2020-06-07&$top=3000`.

When a value exceeding 1000 is given and over 1000 results are available, only the initial 1000 results will be displayed, accompanied by a link to access the subsequent results.

For detailed examples, you can check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents#bkmk_examples).